# Using Direct Proofs in Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, direct-product

Use a direct proof to show that if $x$ is a rational number, then $x^2$ is also a rational number.

I know I need to use the definition of rational numbers but don't know how to do it in this problem.

Comment: Write $x$ as something that follows from the definition of rational numbers. Then try showing that $x^2$ can also be written in similar fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ and $q \ne 0$, hence

$$x^2=\frac{p^2}{q^2}.$$

Conclusion ?

Comment: As long as q² ≠ 0, and p²,q²∈ℤ then x² is a rational number?

Comment: Yes, we have $q \ne 0$, hence $q^2 \ne 0$. Furthermore: $p^2,q^2 \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @JacobMcCullough The big point to be aware of here is that *since* $p,q\in\Bbb Z$ and *since* $q\neq 0$, *the only possibility* is that we must have $p^2,q^2\in\Bbb Z$ and $q^2\neq 0$.  This is because when you multiply two integers together you get another integer and specifically in the case of multiplying two nonzero integers together you get a nonzero integer (*remembering that $p^2=p\times p$ and $q^2=q\times q$*)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me through this Fred & JMoravitz